# C# ASP.NET MVC routing - route for all controllers with specific suffix

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have several controllers for widgets named {WidgetName}WidgetController, e.g. SampleWidgetController. I need to create a route which catches all requests to such controllers and passes them to one common controller together with requested controller's name and action.

```
public class SampleWidgetController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Content()
    {
        ...
    }
}

public class CommonController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Content(string controllerName, string actionName)
    {
        // I want all requests to SampleWidget/Content to be passed here
        // With controllerName = "SampleWidget" and actionName = "Content"
    }
}
```

I can create a custom RouteConstraint to accept only those controllers that have 'Widget' suffix, but I have a problem with defining the route itself which will pass the requested controller's name and action to the common controller.

Comment: why do you want to do this..?? do you plz tell the purpose ..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your RouteConfig `RegisterRoutes` method add the following route **before** the default:

```
routes.MapRoute("Widgets", "{controllerName}Widget/{actionName}",
            new { controller = "Common", action="Content"});
```

This will cause incoming requests matching the format you've specified, e.g. `[baseurl]/testWidget/testaction` would hit your CommonController `Content` Action with a `controllerName="test"` and `actionName="testaction"`

If needed you can then append the "Widget" back onto the `controllerName` variable and pass it into your desired handler / do what you're trying to do.